# Converting X to Standard Units

Tags: statistics

> Let $X$ represent the height.
>
> $E(x) =$ $5$ feet $10$ inches
>
> $SD(X) = 2$
>
> $P(X > 6) = P(X^* > 1)$

$X^*$ is $X$ in standard units.

Why isn't it $P(X^* \gt \frac{6 - (5+\frac{10}{12})}{2}) = P(X^* \gt \frac{1}{12})$

**References:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have $SD(X)=2$ *inches*! (Read the text in the second image).

Your calculations would be OK if you had $SD(X)=2$ ft. But in this case you have
$$\frac{6\text{ ft}-(5\text{ ft}+10\text{ in} \cdot \tfrac{1\text{ ft}}{12\text{ in}})}{2\text{ in}\cdot \tfrac{1\text{ ft}}{12\text{ in}}}=\frac{\tfrac2{12}\text{ ft}}{\tfrac2{12}\text{ ft}}=1,$$
(without units). Or in inches
$$\frac{6 \text{ ft}\cdot \tfrac{12\text{ in}}{1\text{ ft}}-(5\text{ ft}\cdot \tfrac{12\text{ in}}{1\text{ ft}}+10\text{ in})}{2\text{ in}}=\frac{2\text{ in}}{2\text{ in}}=1,$$
(again a dimensionless quantity).

Comment: These American units are confusing!

Comment: They're, aren't they? Come on, US: it's time to go metric!